# unable to import 'sqlite' in visual studio code

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have created a python file import sqlite in vscode. I have installed sqlite in vscode also as you can see in the picture. But it is still showing 'unable to import 'sqlite''. What is the issue?
Please help me resolve this.
[image]

Comment: Are you on a Debian-based Linux distro?

Answer (score 0):

once you installed, i don't think you need to import sqlite, you can straight away write the query statement to query your database

Comment: You have to import sqlite to use it unless you're using some special/magical setup that injects the module into your code.